# How do i do this process *precisely*?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $[a,b)\times [c,d)$ be a rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $\{[u_k,v_k)\times [p_k,q_k)\}_{1≦k≦n}$ be a mutually disjoint finite sequence whose union is $R$.

Then we can decompose this into subintervals of partitions.

When you draw a diagram, it can be achieved by extending sides of each $[u_k,v_k)\times [p_k,q_k)$ to the sides of $[a,b)\times [c,d)$.

How do i do this process *precisely*, so completely get a disjoint finite sequence $\{e_{0,0},...,e_{0,m_0},...,e_{n,0},...,e_{0,m_n}\}$ such that $\bigsqcup_{i=0}^{m_k} e_{k,i} = [u_k,v_k)\times [p_k,q_k)$?

More generally, how can i do this process in $\mathbb{R}^n$? That is, how can i prove that volume of a box and sum of volumes of disjoint boxes whose union is the original box are the same?

I really need to know this... Please help me. Thank you in advance.

EDITED:

Actually, below is what i was going to prove:

Let $S=\{\prod [a_i,b_i) \subset \mathbb{R}^n : a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Define $\mu(\prod [a_i,b_i))=\prod |b_i - a_i|, \forall -\infty < a_i≦b_i< \infty $.

How do i prove that $\mu$ is finitely additive?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to partition $[a,b)$ and $[c,d)$ and take the Cartesian product of the partitions to partition $R$.  Other partitions of $R$ are possible, but maybe this will meet your needs.  You might split $[a,b)$ into three pieces and $[c,d)$ into four, then you will divide $R$ into twelve subrectangles.  Every point of $R$ is accounted for if your subintervals are closed below and open above.  Is that what you mean by precisely?  Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Would you please see my edited post? And i have no idea how to write down "partitioning process" precisely